# How to get the url from link rel="next" in <head> with javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get the url from

```
<link rel="prev" title="Selected 3" href="http://mydomain.com/2.html" />
```

in the head using pure javascript?

In jquery I have a working solution:

```
var prevUrl = $('link[rel=prev]').attr("href");
```

I can't change the output of the "link rel" or add an Id, as it is generated by a CMS.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the reason why you need it done in pure js?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to implement http://padilicious.com/ to let a swipe on an iOS device, go to the next/prev page. I use jQuery so one can use the arrow keys to that. But it seems padilicious.com uses only javascript.

Comment: Sorry link is: http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IE8+

```
document.querySelector('link[rel="prev"]').href;
```

Comment: ...in standards mode, and probably worth adding a `!null` guard on there. The jQuery version won't throw if not found; the above will. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: I personally don't care about IE7. Our policy is *upgrade it or suck it* ;)

Comment: I have accepted this answer, it works, is short, and the code where it is to be used is only for iOS devices. Many, many times thanks, to all of you.

Answer (score 6):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( "link" ),
    filtered = [],
    i = links.length;
while ( i-- ) {
    links[i].rel === "prev" && filtered.push( links[i] );
}

alert( filtered[0].href );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/je7Qr/

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for (var i = 0; typeof(el = links[i]) != "undefined"; i++) {
    if (el.rel == "prev") {
        alert(el.href);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why, *why*, ***why*** constantly re-query the DOM?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's not what `gEBTN` does, it does not do any work by itself.

Comment: @Esailija: No, but that's what Truth's loop does. It calls `getElementsByTagName` repeatedly, as many times as there are `link` elements in the `head` (unless it finds `prev` and breaks). There's absolutely no reason for it. Call it once and walk the result. Bad enough it's a live `NodeList`, recreating it is even more work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It doesn't recreate it: `document.getElementsByTagName("div") === document.getElementsByTagName("div")`. It returns the same NodeList, and returning a NodeList is hardly any work for the browser. It's when you access something in the NodeLIst that it has to calculcate stuff. The equivalent for QuerySelector returns false because it does all work right away, which is why `gEBTN` can seem to be millions of times faster when tested naively.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Esailija is right, the NodeList is cached and updates itself automatically.

Comment: @Esailija: It doesn't make any sense to make a call repeatedly when you can make it only once (particularly not given the layers involved), not from a performance perspective, and not (in my view, this is subjective) from a code comprehension perspective. And (quelle shock) doing so would appear to actually be slower in the real world: http://jsperf.com/remember-result-of-getelementsbytagname ;-) Regardless, though, your `document.getElementsByTagName("div") === document.getElementsByTagName("div")` is an interesting and useful point.

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer: See comment above to Esailija.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your jsfiddle gives me 2x faster for "caching" the result, that difference is comparable between a function call and direct variable, not requerying the dom. If you want to see the difference between DOM querying and not querying it, try queryselectorall which is always forced to query the dom. (1000x difference easily even with small dom)

Comment: @Esailija: I think it's a bit more costly than function call vs. local var, but if you want to create a test on jsperf to demonstrate similar cost, I'd be interested (particularly IE's cost). Regardless, though, thanks again for the `document.getElementsByTagName("div") === document.getElementsByTagName("div")` thing. I'm intrigued by the mechanics of that, internally within browsers. I stand by my code clarity point, but it may be that repeating the call isn't quite as costly as it might seem to be. Still cost without gain, in my view.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you can read staticnodelist vs dynamicnodelist in webkit source, for example, I can't get the links right now though. Yes it does perform faster (and is more readable) but my point was that no dom is being requeried as these methods don't query the dom in the first place.

Comment: Alright. Now you guys are spamming my inbox. Please move this to chat :).